# Build up a cipher instance manually without getInstance

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, jce

I don't seem to figure out a way to "manually" build up instance of cipher. Every tutorial and resource has same way trough Cipher.getInstance

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding");
```

What I'm trying to do is to build up Cipher instance manually by giving it block cipher of my decision, its mode but also padding scheme from my own class hopefully having right methods through interface.

So as a sample trying to do something like:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher(new AESEngine());
...give cipher instance custom class which provides padding scheme
...
```

Upper one was imaginary to explain what I'm after.

Doing this for learning purposes.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. JCA doesn't work the way you wish; what alternatives are you asking about?

Comment: Anything missing from my answer, Ruohonleikkuri? Note that you should always at least provide a tag for the language you are using on StackOverflow, otherwise you will get fewer views, upvotes and answers - and no automatic code highlighting either, but that's less important.

Comment: Nothing missing. Your answer makes perfect sense. I try CipherSpi approach in coming weeks when have time for this again. I then return back here, maybe even with a complete code sample to be reviewed. Thanks for hint with tags.

Answer (score 1):

You are for that looking at the wrong class. To do this you need to implement [CipherSpi](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherSpi.html) - a Service Provider Interface - and then [implement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/howtoimplaprovider.htm#JSSEC-GUID-C485394F-08C9-4D35-A245-1B82CDDBC031) a [Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html) with the right [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/Provider.Service.html). Your SPI should use the software or hardware implementation of the block cipher, in turn.

`Cipher` has explicitly **designed** to require `getInstance`, otherwise you could get around the provider signing and the limited cryptography that is - or used to be - part of the JDK. However, on Android and OpenJDK you don't need to sign the provider anymore.

Other than that you are left with very ugly hacks with reflection etc. to get around the block that `Cipher` poses. You'll have to look those up yourself; as indicated with the latest runtimes there is really no need anymore.

---

If you think that is too complex and you can do with a software only implementation that is not compatible with `Cipher` you can have a look at the Bouncy Castle ["lightweight API"](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

Bouncy Castle also implements a provider in the same way, but due to the size of the code it may be too complex as an example. You could of course decide to integrate your code into BC for your own purposes as well.